# TableRow not fitting screen width

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm developing a xamarin.android app which fill listview adapter from database. The listview entries are displayed in form of tableyout with table rows but the table rows don't fit the screen's width. I am providing you the axml layout code below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/bin"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/binValue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/item"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/itemValue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/customer"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/custValue"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

How do I make the table rows fit the screen's width?